Troubleshooting WebSocket Connection Issue: Python Twitch Chat Integration with HTML Timer
Just want to say that I'm a beginner in programming, and when creating these codes, I used Copilot. My goal was to create a script that reads messages from Twitch chat and, for each new message, adds 1 second to the timer made in HTML. The Python script works perfectly, meaning it outputs each message to the command prompt and, for visualization, adds +1 second to its own timer. However, it cannot connect via WebSocket to the HTML timer. It throws an error in the browser console: 'WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:8082/' failed'. I don't know what to do anymore. Do you have any suggestions on how to fix or optimize this? I would be very grateful.
import asyncio
import threading
import time
import websockets
import json
from twitchio.ext import commands

# Initial timer value in seconds (3 hours)
timer_value = 3 * 60 * 60
timer_lock = threading.Lock()

# List of connected WebSocket clients
ws_clients = []

async def timer_server(websocket, path):
    ws_clients.append(websocket)
    try:
        while True:
            await asyncio.sleep(1)
    except websockets.exceptions.ConnectionClosed:
        pass
    finally:
        ws_clients.remove(websocket)

def timer():
    global timer_value
    while timer_value > 0:
        time.sleep(1)
        with timer_lock:
            timer_value -= 1
            # Send the timer value to all connected WebSocket clients
            for client in ws_clients:
                asyncio.run(client.send(json.dumps({'type': 'timer_update', 'value': timer_value})))

class Bot(commands.Bot):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(token='TOKEN', prefix='!', initial_channels=['NAME'])

    async def event_ready(self):
        print(f'Ready | {self.nick}')

    async def event_message(self, message):
        global timer_value
        print(f"Received message: {message.content}")
        with timer_lock:
            timer_value += 1
            print(f"Updated timer value: {timer_value}")
            # Send the timer value to all connected WebSocket clients
            for client in ws_clients:
                asyncio.create_task(client.send(json.dumps({'type': 'timer_update', 'value': timer_value})))
        await self.handle_commands(message)

# Start the WebSocket server
start_server = websockets.serve(timer_server, 'localhost', 8082)
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(start_server)

# Start the timer in a separate thread
threading.Thread(target=timer).start()

# Run the Twitch bot
bot = Bot()
bot.run()


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Twitch Timer</title>
    <style>
        body {
            font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
            text-align: center;
            background-color: #222; /* Background color */
            color: white; /* Text color */
        }
        #timer {
            font-size: 90px;
            margin-top: 55px;
            background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); /* Semi-transparent black background */
            padding: 10px 20px; /* Padding */
            border-radius: 20px; /* Rounded corners */
            display: inline-block; /* Display as inline-block */
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="timer">3:00:00</div>

    <script>
        // Function to update the timer value on the page
        function updateTimer(hours, minutes, seconds) {
            document.getElementById('timer').textContent = `${hours}:${minutes}:${seconds}`;
        }

        let time = 3 * 60 * 60; // 3 hours in seconds

        // Function for counting down time
        function countdown() {
            setInterval(() => {
                const hours = Math.floor(time / 3600);
                const minutes = Math.floor((time % 3600) / 60);
                const seconds = time % 60;
                updateTimer(hours.toString().padStart(2, '0'), minutes.toString().padStart(2, '0'), seconds.toString().padStart(2, '0'));
                if (time > 0) {
                    time--; // Decrease the timer by 1 second
                }
            }, 1000); // Update the timer every second
        }

        // Connect to the WebSocket server using the secure protocol
        const socket = new WebSocket('wss://localhost:8082');

        // Handling messages from the WebSocket server
        socket.addEventListener('message', function (event) {
            const data = JSON.parse(event.data);
            if (data.type === 'timer_update') {
                time = data.value;
            }
        });

        // Start the countdown when the page loads
        countdown();
    </script>
</body>
</html>


I tried changing the localhost port number, modifying the code, creating connection test code, but nothing helped
